# parsing error when install apk in android 11

Tags: android

when I install my apk in devices with android 11, I get parsing error, but in another devices with lower android version, I have not this problem. how I can solve it?
my apk is very simple, it is just a web view with fcm packages and have not any special permission in manifest file.

Comment: Try to change  higher  ```minSDKVersion```

Comment: Show the error.

Comment: not the minSDKVersion but the targetSdkVersion

Answer (score 0):

Open your build.gradle file and you will see something like this

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 30
    buildToolsVersion "30.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.yourapp"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 30
        versionCode 11
```

Now you have to change the `targetSdkVersion` to `30` or above (only if possible).
Recompile and Install, I should work by now.
Still if it didn't work, include the error log in your question.